# Issue with bpf_xdp_adjust_head

Tags: ebpf, xdp-bpf

Working on a small program with bpf to extend the packet ( ie: add mpls encap).
Managed to extend without issues but I write back the header the s_mac and d_mac are not correct. I'm assuming because the new space is smaller I'm overlapping with the original eth header and thus I get the wrong values.

```
    /* extend the packet for mpls header encapsulation */
    if (bpf_xdp_adjust_head(ctx, 0 - (int)sizeof(struct mpls_hdr)))
        return XDP_DROP;

    data = (void *)(long)ctx->data;
    data_end = (void *)(long)ctx->data_end;

    /* relocate ethernet header to start of packet and set MACs */
    new_eth = data;
    old_eth = data + (int)sizeof(struct mpls_hdr);
    //set new header while swaping src/dst mac
    set_ethhdr(new_eth, old_eth, bpf_htons(ETH_P_MPLS_UC));
```

This is where I believe the problem happens, when I memcpy into new_eth I'm biting into the old_eth space. Is there a way I can solve this by copying the values of the old_eth into another structure and then use that one to create the new_eth ?

```
static __always_inline void set_ethhdr(struct ethhdr *new_eth,
                                       const struct ethhdr *old_eth,
                                       __be16 h_proto)
{
    memcpy(new_eth->h_source, old_eth->h_source, ETH_ALEN);
    memcpy(new_eth->h_dest, old_eth->h_dest, ETH_ALEN);
    new_eth->h_proto = h_proto;
}
```

I'm very new to BPF and C in general so not sure if that's indeed the issue.

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed as per below. Unsure if this is the best way to solve it but it works for my usecase ( poc ).

```
static __always_inline void set_ethhdr(struct ethhdr *new_eth,
                                       const struct ethhdr *old_eth,
                                       __be16 h_proto)
{
    __u8 h_tmp_src[ETH_ALEN];
    __u8 h_tmp_dst[ETH_ALEN];

    __builtin_memcpy(h_tmp_src, old_eth->h_source, ETH_ALEN);
    __builtin_memcpy(h_tmp_dst, old_eth->h_dest, ETH_ALEN);

    __builtin_memcpy(new_eth->h_dest, h_tmp_src, ETH_ALEN);
    __builtin_memcpy(new_eth->h_source, h_tmp_dst, ETH_ALEN);
    
    new_eth->h_proto = h_proto;
}
```